# How do I use underscore .uniq to return a unique array of values?

Tags: arrays, sorting, parse-platform, underscore.js

I'm trying to use underscore .uniq to sort an array but it returns the same array as if unsorted. I think this is because it's sorting by id but I'm not sure. If it is sorting by id, how do I get it to sort along the same lines as the query (allCategories are all of the values by row in the 'primary' column) which is based on the primary column in my Parse collection bizCategories?

My code:

```
var Categories = Parse.Object.extend("bizCategories");

var categories = new Categories();

        $scope.primarySelect = function() {
            var primary = new Parse.Query(Categories);
            primary.find({
                success:function(list){
                    $scope.allCategories = _.uniq(list)
                    console.log($scope.allCategories);
                }
            })
        }
        $scope.primarySelect();
```

The parse collection column 'primary':

[image]

Comment: You don't show the data that you're using. Try something like $scope.allCategories = _.uniq(list,'primary') where primary is a property of the objects in the list.

Comment: whenever I use _.uniq i get back one of three responses: 

1)

Comment: whenever I use _.uniq (sometimes along with _.chain) i get back one of three responses: 

1) _.uniq(list, primary).map(iteratee) returns a single object (there should be 13 as verified by an independent excel function).

2) Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (in most cases)

2 _ {_wrapped: Array[100], _chain: true, after: function, all: function, any: function…}

3) (when using chain then map then uniq after the iteratee) function () {
        var args = [this._wrapped];
        push.apply(args, arguments);
        return result.call(this, func.apply(_, args));
      }

Comment: ok, after some tinkering, i see what you mean and got it to work. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the unique values for just the "primary" field, you would do it as follows:

```
var primaryList = _.map(list, function(item) { return item.get('primary'); });
var uniquePrimaryList = _.uniq(primaryList);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Things like this made the difference in the beginning. Thanks once again.